# Objective c nib frame size for family iPhone on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I made a nib for each viewController with family "iPhone" in the selection the GUI wizard offers. I have it working on iPad & iPhone (without separate iPad nibs) because I can't be bothered and I don't see the point. I'd rather just have one nib for all (especially now that the new iPhone 5 is out (with a different screen size).

On one of my pages on iPad the view is left aligned and the size of an iPhone (because of family : iPhone). What is the best way to get these nibs working on both? Do I need to reset the frame.width & frame.height after I have init'd my viewControlers? I.E by setting it to something like window.width?

EDIT:What I've come up with is below, is this going to be safe code?

In every viewDidLoad method on every VC I will do this:

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use one xib/nib file for iPhone and iPad interfaces it is set appropriate autoresing masks of your `UIView`s [AppleDocs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask):

> An integer bit mask that determines how the receiver resizes itself when its superview’s bounds change.

In iOS 6 it is now released new method to make autoresing:

> Use layout constraints to automatically position the views (iOS 6 and later). You override updateViewConstraints to add any necessary layout constraints not already configured by the views. Your implementation of this method must call [super updateViewConstraints].

You could try to find more information here: [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853)